# Keep mesh volume during deformation based on rotation

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting

I'm working on a project which includes a book opening and turning pages. Right now I'm trying to rig the book. Since I can't animate every page individually, I've thought about having a few more detailed individual pages for close ups and "bulk pages" for filling up the rest.

The bulk pages are a single blender object with many planes.

I'm working on deforming the bulk pages. I have a decent system that doesn't rely on keyframing bones, I parented the pages to the spine of the book and by rotating the spine, the pages follow, based on a weight painting (a simple gradient). It's really simple. I also have other controls for shearing the pages and bending the other side that's not bound to the spine. On a single page it gives a really nice result. On the bulk ones I have an issue:

[image]

[image: ooo]

The problems is pretty obvious, there is some bad pinching/loss of volume when the spine turns. I'm not sure how to solve this. I tried adding more geometry for the base mesh, but it doesn't really change the result.

Any suggestions? I'm using modifiers and not geometry nodes if that's important.

Comment: Nobody has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This used a curve modifier on a simple cube representing the bulk pages and binding. (Blend file below)

[image]

The cube/book is originally laid flat and it's origin point (OP) set to it's binding end at left.

The cube's edges (not the binding area) are generously subdivided so it can be deformed smoothly by the curve modifier.

[image]

A curve is added at that same location, but it's OP is moved to it's leftmost ctl-point. (left end)
That is then moved to the book's OP so both the curve and book share the same location.
(SH-S)

The book is then given a Curve Modifier and should not move when this is done.

The book's OP is also used to add a master handle (circle empty - a parent) for both the curve and book.
(The handle isn't essential but it's handy when the book, curve, and other associated items are to be relocated or realigned)

With the curve and book parented to the handle, the handle was then rotated to the vertical so the binding (& curve) sits upright.

.

In Edit mode, the curve's 1st two ctl-points (at bottom) are subdivided 3 times so we have 4 ctl-points down there which are  --> Never to be used <--

[image]

When the other (higher) ctl-points are moved to bend the pages, the binding is pretty much left alone and remains vertical.

.

To emulate how the rightmost page edges would shrink back when opened, a single hook is used to bring the upper edge back.  Note the location of this hook and it's settings in the attached Blend file. (select the book to see them)

To further insulate the binding the hook's influence is connected to the page vertices only, not the binding's.  (See the vertice group in the Blend file)

I imagine you could do the same thing in reverse for the book's left side.

[image]